# Handling error timeout expired. Max pool size connection was reached in vs 2005

Tags: mysql, vb.net, error-handling

Sorry for this mainstream post. after doing a long digging to this problem, i've never really found the solution yet. many cause that could trigger this problem.
so i bring up this post to ask for some understanding.

I'm manipulating database.. populating them into array, list, compare, and then storing back them again in database. in all of that process i use many query like `ExecuteScalar` and `MysqlCommand`, resulting in creating a lot of `new mysqlcommand` in `module.vb`

I'm using vb.net and xampp mysql as data server..
and i have 2 database: they're same but different in size..

**the problem is**: when i'm testing the 2nd database (the smaller size in records amount)
my program works well without delay or timeout period error`

but when i'm changing the datasource with my 1st database (with 4900 records), the `timeout expired` popped up directly, causing my vs 2005 become not responding

as per my research on google, i've found few explanation for this error

1. vs 2005 still has a bug, and that is `timeout expired`. the solution is to upgrade vs version
2. the error raised because attempting to open the same connection on the same server.
3. this error message is not exactly mean what it says. it tells you that the connection was full, but in reality the connection's slot is still available
4. i'm using too much `mysqlcommand` variable as i've in `module.vb` as many as *50 mysqlcomand variable !!!*

my personal opinion: i can't apply the first solution.. my program will have a lot of error if i were to upgrading it into vs 2010 or higher

for the second solution: i don't really understand what's that mean. i think that's because i'm trying to open the same connection (example CMD_open1. executereader) again, but that same connection is already open and hasn't been closed

in my program i've already ensure that everytime i'm using CMD.execute reader or executenonquery or execute scalar, i add the `CMD name.connection.dispose()`, to close the connection properly between open another new one

**so my question now is**

1. did all my personal speculation correct? if not, please tell me the correct ones
2. based on my problem, personally i think the cause is i'm using too much `mysqlcommand`, even i did close the connection everytime i used. is that correct? what is the right explanation for this?
3. what is the proper solution that i could apply to fix my problem?

thx for reading. i really crave for the answer for this problem.

here's the ss of my `module.vb` that contains lot of `mysqlcommand` variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some serious refactoring.

Databases-related objects are ***expensive***. The more you instantiate, the more you pay in performance penalties. They are also ***scarce***. You will *run out* eventually (sooner rather than later). You need to be very judicious in your use of them and be sure to clean them up appropriately when you're finished.

Many programmers put all of the database-related objects into (essentially) a single function which handles all the cleanup, etc.:

```vb
Private Function RunQuery( ByVal procName As String ) As DataTable
    Using l_connection = new MySqlConnection("connection info")
        Using l_command = New MySqlCommand( procName )
            l_command.CommandType = StoredProcedure

            ' ... etc ...

            Return l_results
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

The `Using` blocks ensure that the database objects are cleaned up properly after each call (calling the appropriate `Close` and `Dispose` functions).

But it sounds like you've already got some good advice about what the potential issues might be. The list you provided is pretty much what I would recommend. It's up to you to test and debug to figure out which one of those is causing the problem.

Also, [mainstream support for Visual Studio 2005 ended in 2011](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Visual+Studio+2005). If you can't be bothered to upgrade your tools to fix known bugs (because it'll be too much work for you), then there's not much more to say on the subject other than, "Don't complain when you run into bugs."

Comment: oh you're right.. i forgot to ask.. which one is better? closing the connection with function or dispose?

and also what is the difference in `CMD.connection.dispose()` and `CMD.connection.close`. Every time i use connection, i always close it with `dispose` not both. what is the most proper way ?

Comment: @SoniGunz - Close is sufficient. Dispose calls Close. Best practice is to use resource-intensive objects in a [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to guarantee proper disposal.